# how do I fix this issue in my code. "Argument 1: cant convert string to bool"

Tags: c#, if-statement

```
using System;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("How goes the day?");

            string day = Console.ReadLine();
            if (day == Console.ReadKey("Good")) < -----heres the issue
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Good to hear");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should look up the documentation for the Console.ReadKey method

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.readkey?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: IMHO, just call `if ("Good" == Console.ReadLine()) ` etc.. since you're not even using that var besides comparison and that's it.

Comment: The documentation is indeed a *very* good way to learn about the thousands of classes, methods, properties and the like.  But VS also presents pop up reminders regarding the operation, signature, return and arguments for methods *as you type*.  It is called *Intellisense*.

Answer (score 0):

`Console.ReadKey()` will only read the next key that is entered by the user. `Console.ReadLine()` will read the entire input of a user into the console for that line.

I would go check user input using the following which is short and sweet:

```cs
if (Console.ReadLine().Equals("good"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Good to hear");
}
```

**EDIT:** Removed incorrect information about string equality. `String.equals()` is the same as `string == string`, it is just up to personal preference. You can read more about it on [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/how-to/compare-strings).

Comment: Whoops, I'm getting confused with Java, I'll correct it now. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score -1):

You are calling the Console.ReadKey method unnecessarily.

There is plenty of documentations and tutorials that can get you going. Some of the other users have given you links. Follow them and learn. The best way to learn is by doing and as this is the very basic of codes, you should try and learn by searching and doing some tutorials. I am not having a go, its the best way to learn.

```
    string day = Console.ReadLine();
    if (day == "Good")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Good to hear");
    }
```